# Sum of a rectangular and a triangular distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

It is given that $X \sim R(0,1)$ and the density of $Y$ is given as:

$f(y)=
\begin{array}{cc}
  \Bigg\{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      y & 0<y<1 \\
      2-y & 1<y<2 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{array}
\end{array}
$

$X,Y$ are independent.

Find the distribution of $X+Y$

I had the following approach.
Let $Z=X+Y$

**Case 1 : $0<z<2$**

$P(Z \le z)=P(Z \le z| 0 < Y < 1)P(0 < Y < 1)+ P(Z \le z|1 < Y <2)P(1<Y<2)$

$=(\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{z-x} y \ \text{dy} \ \text{dx}) \frac{1}{2}+(\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1}^{z-x} 2-y \ \text{dy dx})\frac{1}{2}$

**Case 2:$2<z<3$**
$P(Z \le z)=P(Z \le z|1<Y<2)P(1<Y<2)=(\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1}^{z-x} 2-y \ \text{dy dx}) \frac{1}{2}$

Is this approach correct?

Comment: How can $z>3$ occur? Maximum value of $z$ is $3$

Comment: Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, wouldn't the joint distribution exist only in the range $0<y<1$, density of $X$ being zero elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer in that I show the results but not the logic leading to the results.  (However, that should probably give you enough hints to provide the missing steps.)

Using *Mathematica* one can get the pdf for the sum:

```
distSum = TransformedDistribution[
  x + y, {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 
   y \[Distributed] TriangularDistribution[{0, 2}]}]
FullSimplify[PDF[distSum, z]]
```

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{z^2}{2} & 0<z\leq 1 \\
 -(z-3) z-\frac{3}{2} & 1<z\leq 2 \\
 \frac{1}{2} (z-3)^2 & 2<z<3 \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$$

Generate some random samples of the sum.

```
n = 10000;
SeedRandom[12345];
xx = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], n];
yy = RandomVariate[TriangularDistribution[{0, 2}], n];
```

Display results:

```
Show[Histogram[xx + yy, Automatic, "PDF"],
 Plot[PDF[distSum, z], {z, 0, 3}]]
```

[image: PDF and histogram of sum]